# Как создать неинициализированную глобальную переменную размером в 4 байта?

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Здраствуйте, подскажите, верно ли выполнено первое задание и как можно реализовать второе задание? Использую Fasm и X64dbg.

1. Вычислить арифметическое выражение a*b+a*(c+d)+d*(-1) . Переменные a, b, c, d в начале выполнения программы должны быть расположены в регистрах eax, ebx, ecx и edx соответственно. Численные значения можно взять произвольными.
2. Создать неинициализированную глобальную переменную размером в 4 байта, программно инициализировать ее таким образом, чтобы в окне дампа можно было увидеть AA BB CC DD.

```
format PE GUI
entry start
 
a dd 2
b dd 3
c dd 4
d dd 5
e dd ?
 
start:
                            
mov eax,[a]                 
mov ebx,[b]                
mov ecx,[c]                
mov edx,[d]
add ebx,ecx
add ebx,edx
mul eax
sub edx,eax
mov [e],edx
 
ret
```

Comment: Вторая часть - или как вы делаете через `e dd ?`, или `e rd`. Программно инициализирвать - через mov, например, `mov [e], 0xDDCCBBAA`. Но это в целом разные вопросы, лучше не задавать два вопроса в одном.

Comment: В вашем коде выше уже есть создание неинициализированной переменной размером в 4 байта — переменная `e`

Comment: Вычисление примера из пункта один не полное и ошибочное.